# How to run test component coding before installation in joomla?

Tags: joomla, components

How to run test component coding before installation in joomla ?
Example:
Normally we are created install.xml, test.php ..

How to test it ?

Answer (score 0):

What is to be tested? Do you want to test component without installation? Not sure it is possible but you could try to write this in you browser address line

index.php?option=com_newcomponent

and create folder `components/newcomponent/` with file `newcomponent.php`.
If you want to write new component but don't want to write `install.php` manually, I would suggest you to use [this extention](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/5908) . With easyCreator you can really easy create components/modules/pluins with predefined templates. New extention will be installed automatically. When you finish to develop your extention you download installation package for transport it to other sites.

Sorry for messed english :)(BTW, how is it?:)) I tried to be clear. I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: it mean when i creating component how can i test component before installation.

Comment: Yes. You can run new component without installation. To achieve this you should create new folder `/components/newcomponent/`, create file `/components/newcomponent/newcomponent.php` and follow the link `http://www.site.com/index.php?option=com_newcomponent`. This should work.